# python pandas join to one row

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am wanting to join two dateframes together with a left join but want every matched items be be joined to just one row in the resulting dateframe.

e.g.

```
df1:

company, clientid
tesco,   1
argos,   2
MnS,     3

df2:

info, clientid
a,    1
b,    1
c,    1
d,    2
g,    3
z,    5
```

wanted result:

```
company, clientid, info, info, info
tesco,   1,        a,    b,    c
argos,   2,        d
MnS,     3,        g
```

Using:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='clientid', how='left')
```

Causes the rows in df1 to be duplicated for the merge to work creating what I would call a uni file and not a flat file which I would like.

Answer (score 1):

We can groupby 'clientid' and then create a series from the unique values and call reset_index. This creates a df with the info columns as ordinal int values which we need to rename.

We can then merge this back to the original df:

```
In [42]:

df_info = df1.groupby('clientid')['info'].unique().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
info_len = len([col for col in df_info if str(col).isdigit()])
df_info.columns = ['clientid'] + ['info'] * info_len
df_info
Out[42]:
   clientid info info info
0         1    a    b    c
1         2    d  NaN  NaN
2         3    g  NaN  NaN
3         5    z  NaN  NaN
In [43]:

df.merge(df_info, on='clientid', how='left')
Out[43]:
  company  clientid info info info
0   tesco         1    a    b    c
1   argos         2    d  NaN  NaN
2     MnS         3    g  NaN  NaN
```

Breaking down the individual groupby operations shows what is happening:

```
In [44]:

df1.groupby('clientid')['info'].unique()
Out[44]:
clientid
1           [a, b, c]
2                 [d]
3                 [g]
5                 [z]
Name: info, dtype: object
In [45]:

df1.groupby('clientid')['info'].unique().apply(pd.Series)
Out[45]:
          0    1    2
clientid             
1         a    b    c
2         d  NaN  NaN
3         g  NaN  NaN
5         z  NaN  NaN
In [46]:

df1.groupby('clientid')['info'].unique().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
Out[46]:
   clientid  0    1    2
0         1  a    b    c
1         2  d  NaN  NaN
2         3  g  NaN  NaN
3         5  z  NaN  NaN
```

The rest of the code following the above should be self-explanatory

Comment: Your method works well. But am struggling to apply it when there are multiple columns in the df1.

Comment: Can you edit your post with sample data and code to explain your problem